# Python thinks 100 is less than 50?

Tags: python, arrays, windows, file, numbers

here is my code:

```
stock_file  = open('Task_3_1.txt', "rt") #open file
stock_lines = stock_file.readlines() #convert items to list
total_buys = []
total_cost = []
done = 0
for o in range(0,(len(stock_lines)-1)): 
    edit = list(stock_lines[o])
    for m in range(1,2): #convert file to array
        edit.remove(edit[len(edit)-1])
    stock_lines[o] = ''.join(edit)
to_do = input("1. Find items that need to be restocked\n")
if to_do == "1":    
    x = 1
    while x < len(stock_lines):
        if stock_lines[x] < stock_lines[x+1]:        
            print(stock_lines[x-1], "needs restocking (" + stock_lines[x] +  " stock, restock level is", stock_lines[x+1] +")")
        x+=4 #increases x to check the next item
```

My problem is that when run, it's meant to print out what stuff needs restocking (which stock levels are lower than the restock level). Here is the stock file I'm using:

```
Egg
100
50
75
Crocodile clip
30
12
30
Chocolate
206
300
390
```

The first line is item name, then stock level, then restock level, then target stock level (the amount of stock the item will have when restocked).

When I run this:

```
1. Find items that need to be restocked
1
Egg needs restocking (100 stock, restock level is 50)
Chocolate needs restocking (206 stock, restock level is 300)
```

As you can see, it's telling me 100 is less than 50. Any help would be great.

I already tried changing 100 to 101 to see if the double zero affected it.

Comment: Are you by any chance comparing `"100" < "50"` string to string?

Comment: Um... your title **"Python thinks 100 is more than 50?"** is probably not really what you meant to say...

Comment: As a side-note, I guess you should edit the`if to_do == "1"` to `if to_do == 1` it did not work for me until I changed it to integer comparison.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> '100' < '50'
True
>>> 100 < 50
False
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Answer (score 1):

you're comparing *strings*.

```
"100" < "50"
```

because 1 comes before 5.

Fix as follows:

```
if int(stock_lines[x]) < int(stock_lines[x+1]):
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to `int(stock_lines[x]) < int(stock_lines[x+1])`.